# Cuando se utiliza in.close(); de la clase Scanner?

Tags: java, eclipse, scanner

Estoy intentando compilar el programa para saber si es par o impar y me aparece un error "Resource leak: input never close" , donde es recomendable cerrar el Scanner?

```
package pares;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pares {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numero;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("introduzca un numero");
    numero = input.nextInt();

    if(esPar(numero)){
        System.out.println("el numero"+numero+"el numero es par." );
    } else {
        System.out.println("el numero"+numero+"el numero es impar.");
    }
} // if 
    public static boolean esPar( int numero){
      if( numero % 2 == 0 )
          return true;
      else{
          return false;
      }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es cerrar el `Scanner`, el cual por dentro cerrará el recurso `System.in`. Si usas Java 7 o superior, puedes usar el `try-with-resources`:

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("introduzca un numero");
    numero = input.nextInt();
    //resto del código del método main...
}
```

En caso de usar Java 6 o inferior, debes llamar al método `Scanner#close` manualmente. La mejor manera de hacer esto es dentro de un bloque `try-finally`:

```
Scanner input = null;
try {
    input = new Scanner(System.in)
    System.out.println("introduzca un numero");
    numero = input.nextInt();
    //resto del código del método main...
} catch (Exception e) {
    //manejar la excepción
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno yo tiro a hacerte unos ternarios para perfeccionar y que quedes de vicio. Así el ejercicio es más rápido.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pares
{

```
private static Scanner input;
private static boolean cerrarScanner;


public static void main(String[] args)
{

try
{

    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduzca un número");
    int numero = input.nextInt();

    imprimir(numero);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // puedes manejar un log si quieres aunque para el ejercicio que es
    // igual es un poco mucho
}
finally
{
    cerrarScanner();
}
}


/**
 * @param numero
 */
public static void imprimir(int numero)
{

if(esPar(numero))
{
    System.out.println("El número " + numero + " el número es par.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("El número " + numero + " el número es impar.");
}
}


public static boolean esPar(int numero)
{

// puedes usar un ternario si quieres
boolean esPar = (numero % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
return esPar;

}


public static void cerrarScanner()
{

cerrarScanner = (input != null) ? true : false;
input.close();

}
```

}

Comment: hice un pasito mal en el método cerrarScanner(), no lo tengamos en cuenta

Comment: public static void cerrarScanner()
    {

 if(input != null)
 {
     input.close();
 }

    }